# How to pass a range in a def function

Tags: python, function

Want to pass a range for the web-scraping function, not sure how it's done. This is to make my code more reusable so that I can scrape different ranges with different dates, say 2016... 2017... 2018... Code looks like this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import requests

def game_id2017(game_id):
    games_played_2017 = []
    games_played_2018 = []

    print('Getting data...')
    for game_id in range():
        url = 'https://statsapi.web.nhl.com/api/v1/game/{}/boxscore'.format(game_id)
        r_2017 = requests.get(url)
        game_data_2017 = r_2017.json()

        for homeaway in ['home','away']:

            game_dict_2017 = dict()
            game_dict_2017['team'] = game_data_2017.get('teams').get(homeaway).get('team').get('name')
            game_dict_2017['teamID'] = game_data_2017.get('teams').get(homeaway).get('team').get('id')
            game_dict_2017['homeaway'] = homeaway
            game_dict_2017['game_id'] = game_id
            games_played_2017.append(game_dict_2017)

game_id2017(20170201, 20170210, 1) 
TypeError: game_id2017() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given
```

Comment: you have to use this: `def game_id2017(*game_id): for i in game_id: pass`

Comment: You probably need `def game_id2017(*args)`, then `for game_id in range(*args)`. Do not use the same variable as an argument for the function and then as a loop variable.

Comment: Thank you for the help, much appreciated! Excuse me for the stupid question, should have googled better..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
game_id2017(*game_id)
```

for id in game_id:
then use game_id like a list

Answer (score 0):

Pass a list:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import requests

def game_id2017(game_id):

    print('Getting data...')
    for a_game_id in range(len(game_id)):
       # use a_game_id

game_id2017([20170201, 20170210, 1])
```